# SQL Server : change strings in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, date, format

I have about 2 million rows in my table with a column for dates... this column is of type `VARCHAR`, and it contains a wrong date format, we have this format `dd/mm/YYYY` and it must be `YYYY-mm-dd`...

How can I change it? Remember it is a `Varchar` column, not a `Datetime` column (and it can't be datetime field because we manipulate it with our queries)

Thank you in advice.

**UPDATE**

As I said, I have MILLIONS of rows, so it's not possible to query one by one the date field to a new one, as you said in your responses.... I need some kind of "automatic" mode to transfer every row to it's new format and datatype column.

Comment: *it contains a wrong date format* - **no** - it's the **wrong datatype** - period. You can also manipulate `DATETIME` columns - no problem at all - that's **not** a valid excuse to use the wrong datatype... read (and **embrace!**) Read [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: I know... But I did an import from MySQL and it was trhowing me errors when I tried to move that field, so I changed to varchar to get it working, but we made a mistake when importing the values, so the date format was wrong... So if I can change the format, I think I could change the datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your end goal is just cleanup to end up in a datetime column, you only need to add a new column, then transfer the data:

```
update tbl
   set new_datetime_col = convert(datetime, dateinvarchar, 103);
```

---

**Query**:

```
update tbl
   set dateinvarchar = convert(char(10),
                       convert(datetime,
                               dateinvarchar, 103), 121)
select * from tbl
```

**Sample table**:

```
create table tbl (dateinvarchar varchar(10));
insert tbl values
  ('01/02/2012'),
  ('02/02/2012'),
  ('03/02/2012'),
  ('14/12/2012');
```

**[Sample Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/550c6/2/0)**:

```
| DATEINVARCHAR |
-----------------
|    2012-02-01 |
|    2012-02-02 |
|    2012-02-03 |
|    2012-12-14 |
```

Comment: Update statements work on multiple rows, or the entire table in the absence of a WHERE clause, as shown. Be it one row or a million, the same statement will process the entire table.

Comment: Thanks it worked, after updating to the new format, I've changed datatype to "date" :) thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Declare @t table (dt varchar(25));
insert into @t
SELECT '01/01/2012' UNION 
SELECT '02/01/2012' UNION
SELECT '03/01/2012'

SELECT convert(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, dt, 103), 120) as dt_new
from @t;


CREATE TABLE newT(id, dt varchar(10));
INSERT INTO newT
SELECT id, convert(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, dt, 103), 120) as dt_new
    from oldT;
```

Comment: @user1381537 check my updated answer, i'm not sure why do you think my query is working on few rows and not all from table? It will convert dt columns for all rows. I used sample data to show how to do that. You need to replace @t with your original table

Comment: I supossd that because I saw 3 SELECT statements... the way you explained, I must make a new table... but what if I just want to use the same table, but move "date_field" to "newdate_field" in the same table?

Comment: Ok i managed to do it but.... instead insert the new values to the new field, on the same IDS... It adds new rows so I got 1.6 more million rows with everything as NULL but the new date T_T

Insert into Banksphere (ficha) 
SELECT convert(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, fecha, 103), 120) as dt_new
from Banksphere